# Calling Store from App.JS

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc, extjs4.1

I am in the app.js file. there is a function that gets executed when user logs in to the stytem successfully;

```
loginSuccess: function() {

this.getViewport().getLayout().setActiveItem(1).store.load();   // Calls the Store of the i need to navigate 
        this.getViewport().getLayout().setActiveItem(1);  // The view i will be navigating

}
```

I am getting an error stating `this.getViewport().getLayout().setActiveItem(1).store is undefined`. i think i'm calling the Store the wrong way. how could i correct this ? How can i call the Store from the app.js ?

**UPDATE**

```
var st = Ext.getStore('myStore');
        st.load();
        st.on('load', function() { 
            this.getViewport().getLayout().setActiveItem(1);  


        });
```

Comment: what's the item you want to set active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct way to initiate store loading is:

```
var st = Ext.getStore('MyStore');
st.load();
```

just remember that loading is async process, so if you want something to be executed after store is loaded you can't just write a code after `load()` - you would need to subscribe to the `load` event.

Comment: What do you mean by subscribe to the `load` method ?

Comment: `st.on('load', function() { got_something_her });`

Comment: Do you mean to write `this.getViewport().getLayout().setActiveItem(1); ` inside the `st.on('load',function() .....` ?

Comment: This is to display the 2nd view when login is successful. Before i show this 2nd view, i am Loading the records from the Store, and then displaying the view which would show those records.

Comment: then yes, in that event handler function do you setActive

Comment: I have updated my Post with the code, but i get an error `this.getViewport is not a function` . Could you help me ?

Comment: You have scope issue. Handler is not being called in the same scope original function was. Add one more `this` parameter when subscribing to the event. And I recommend very strongly to walk-through Sencha MVC application guide. You will feel yourself much more comfortable with the framework.

Comment: You mean `this.this.getViewport().getLayout().setActiveItem(1);` ?

Comment: No, i mean add parameter to `on` function: st.on('load', function() {}, this) - check out documentation http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Element-method-on